# Mysql subquery returns more than 1 row when insert multiple records at once

Tags: php, mysql

i have scan_freq column in dr_scan table.
I am trying to insert records to the dr_scan table and if there is any duplicate value, it will change the duplicate row scan_freq column to 0 otherwise it stays 1.

so I developed the below-noted code and it worked as I expected.
But when I try to insert multiple records at once with duplicate values it will return " subquery returns more than 1 row when insert multiple records at once"

```
if ($savec == "confirm") 
{ 
    $checkIfExistsQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM dr_scan WHERE barcode = (SELECT barcode FROM temp_scan_save WHERE user_id='$user_id' )"; 
    $checkResult = mysqli_query($conn, $checkIfExistsQuery); 
    $rowCount = mysqli_fetch_assoc($checkResult)['count']; 
    if ($rowCount > 0) 
    {
         $updateSql = "UPDATE dr_scan SET scan_freq = 0 WHERE barcode = (SELECT barcode FROM temp_scan_save WHERE user_id='$user_id' )"; 
         $updateResult = mysqli_query($conn, $updateSql); 
     } 
        $insertSql = "INSERT INTO dr_scan (barcode, machine_type, line, date, user_id, device_id, center, mstatus, mstatus_changed, live_status, transfer_status, scan_freq) SELECT barcode, machine_type, line, date, user_id, device_id, center, mstatus, mstatus_changed, live_status, transfer_status, 1 as scan_frequency FROM temp_scan_save WHERE user_id='$user_id'"; 
        $insertResult = mysqli_query($conn, $insertSql); 
        if (isset($updateResult) && $updateResult && isset($insertResult) && $insertResult)
         { $response = array("response" => "success"); echo json_encode($response); 
        } else 
        { 
            $response = array("response" => "failure"); echo json_encode($response);
         } 
         $sql2 = "DELETE FROM temp_scan_save WHERE user_id='$user_id' "; $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2); } 
         else { }
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `barcode` is a unique key in `dr_scan`, you can use one [IODKU](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) and one [DELETE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) statement. You should be using [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating strings together.

```php
if ($savec == 'confirm') {
    $insertSql = <<<'SQL'
            INSERT INTO dr_scan (barcode, machine_type, line, date, user_id, device_id, center, mstatus, mstatus_changed, live_status, transfer_status, scan_freq)
            SELECT barcode, machine_type, line, date, user_id, device_id, center, mstatus, mstatus_changed, live_status, transfer_status, 1 as scan_frequency
            FROM temp_scan_save
            WHERE user_id = ?
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE scan_freq = 0
            SQL;
    $insertResult = $conn->execute_query($insertSql, [$user_id]);

    echo json_encode(['response' => ($insertResult ? 'success' : 'failure')]);

    $conn->execute_query('DELETE FROM temp_scan_save WHERE user_id = ?', [$user_id]);

} else {}
```